# Reducing quantile & color map queries for use with Associations

Tags: probability-or-statistics, associations, code-review, query

This set of queries perform basic maps to quantile and then color-map. There's got to be a more compact solution. What are some approaches to reduction?

**Numeric:**

```
quantileAssociation[p_List][x_] := 
  AssociationThread[p -> Quantile[x, p]];

quantileIntervals[p_List] := 
  Query[quantileAssociation[p] /* Normal /* (Partition[#, 2, 1] &) /* 
    Query[Association /* Map[Interval], Transpose /* Apply[Rule], 
     Apply[List]]];

toQuantile[qtl_Association][x_] := 
  qtl // Query[Select[IntervalMemberQ[#, x] &] /* Keys /* First];

quantileMap[p_List][x_] := 
  x // Query[All, toQuantile[quantileIntervals[p][x]]];
```

**Graphic:**

```
quantileColors[colors_][p_List] := 
  p //  AssociationMap[colors] /* 
    Query[Normal /* (Partition[#, 2, 1] &) /* 
      Query[Association /* Map[Blend], Transpose /* Apply[Rule], 
       Apply@List]];

quantileColorMap[p_List] := 
  With[{colors = quantileColors[ColorData["TemperatureMap"]][p]},
   Query[quantileMap[p]] /* Query[All, colors[#] &]];
```

**Walkthrough**

Using minimal dataset:

```
qts = Range[0, 1, 1/4];

ds = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10] // MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &] // 
   Association /* KeyMap[FromLetterNumber] // Dataset
```

[image]

```
ds[quantileAssociation[qts]] // Normal
```

> <|0 -> 1, 1/4 -> 4, 1/2 -> 6, 3/4 -> 9, 1 -> 10|>

associates input data values to the parameter quantiles, eg here 6 is the median (1/2 quantile).

Then group into intervals,

```
ds[quantileIntervals[qts]] // Normal
```

> <|{0, 1/4} -> Interval[{1, 4}], {1/4, 1/2} ->    Interval[{4, 6}],
>   {1/2, 3/4} -> Interval[{6, 9}], {3/4, 1} ->    Interval[{9, 10}]|>

finally map input values to quantile intervals,

```
ds[quantileMap[qts]] // Normal
```

> <|"a" -> {1/2, 3/4}, "b" -> {1/2, 3/4}, "c" -> {1/2, 3/4},   "d" ->
>   {0, 1/4}, "e" -> {0, 1/4}, "f" -> {1/4, 1/2},   "g" -> {1/2, 3/4}, "h"
>   -> {3/4, 1}, "i" -> {0, 1/4}, "j" -> {0, 1/4}|
>    >

also for use in `quantileColorMap`.

```
{ds[quantileMap@qts], ds[quantileColorMap@qts]}
```

[image]

**Fancy Application:**

Using the functions above, the graphic shows outliers (using quantiles `{0,1/10,9/10,1}`=  ie bottom 10%, middle 80%, top 10%) in doctors' responses to 7-item NASA TLX task load survey (each column of squares) across multiple patients (each row represents a visit). D07 saw 7 patients and most of the responses are in the bottom 10% of all scores (per item) regardless of patient.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated but also note `Dataset` type system mixes real and rational values.

Comment: I replaced `code-golf` with `code-review` as I think that fits your intent better.

Comment: I tried to mentally walk through this code and I got lost.  Would you add some written description of what is going on here?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, will do. Readability would greatly increase with operator form for everything + use of infix.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, added walkthrough.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: Feel free to close, stale code.